# why im not getting result displayed via ajax shorthand

Tags: jquery, ajax, .post

I'm trying to pull some json data via ajax shorthand method. Called via a text keyup, it works fine, but fails when called by button submit. Please somebody help.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#emcode').keyup(function(){
        var length=$('#emcode').val().length;
        if (length > 4){
            var emcodeValue=$('#emcode').val();
            $.post('jason.php',{emcode: emcodeValue},function(result){          
                $('#feedback').html(result).show();
            }); 
        };
    }); 
});

$('#data-submit').click(function(){
    var length=$('#emcode').val().length;
    if (length > 4){
        var emcodeValue=$('#emcode').val();
        $.post('jason.php',{emcode: emcodeValue},function(result){          
            $('#feedback').html(result).show();
        }); 
    };
});
```

Comment: Try to surround your click event by `$(document).ready(function(){ … });`.

Comment: Thank you KittMedia, I made like this , but no result. Im using latest jquery.   $(document).ready(function(){
     
  function pullData(){
 
   var length=$('#emcode').val().length;
   if (length > 4){
   var emcodeValue=$('#emcode').val();
   $.post('jason.php',{emcode: emcodeValue},function(result){   
   $('#feedback').html(result).show();
  }); 
  };  
  }
 
 });

Comment: Thanks all, I have fixed as follows. But solution is to post only. The button action is assigned to javascript and script is having a separate function for that. as : `code` $(document).ready(function(){});
 
     function postData(){  
  var length=$('#name').val().length;
  if (length > 4){   
  var emcodeValue=$('#name').val();
  window.alert(emcodeValue);
     $.post('jasonSTORE.php',{name: emcodeValue},function(result){  
     
  }); 
  
        document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML="Hi Doa";  
  
  };
  };

Comment: @jraisanen thanks for edit.

Comment: I learnt that calling like var variAble = function{ $.ajax(.....return data)} will give response to the varaiab